# Doubletap recognizer for message bubbles (Messagekit)

Tags: swift, messagekit

I want to add the feature to double tap a given message bubble.

Code so far:

```
@objc func doubleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("double tap called")
}

func messageStyle(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> MessageStyle {
    
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: messagesCollectionView, action: #selector(doubleTap(gesture:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    
    let sender = message.sender
    if sender.senderId == selfSenderEmail?.senderId {
        // Self Message
        return .bubbleTailOutline(.blue, .bottomRight, .curved)
    }
    // More if statements for groupchat color coding
    return .bubbleTailOutline(.darkGray, .bottomLeft, .curved)
}
```

I get this Error Thread 1: "-[MessageKit.MessagesCollectionView doubleTapWithGesture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f94c7112a00".

If you think my post isn't clear in anyway, please let me know so I can clarify it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `UITapGestureRecognizer` on view from `MessagesViewController`, which will attach it to the same controller view for each cell.

I suppose we are trying to get a double-tap for `message cell` and in order to achieve that, add `UITapGestureRecognizer` in the cell that you are trying to get the double tap on.

Suppose, we have `DoubleTappableCell`, which can be a text cell, media cell, or any other message.

```swift
class DoubleTappableCell: MessageContentCell {
    
    lazy var doubleTapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        return tapGesture
    }()
    
    var onDoubleTapped: () -> Void = {}
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)
    }
    
    @objc func doubleTapped() {
        onDoubleTapped()
    }
}
```

This cell will be returned from the `MessageCollectionView`.

```swift
public override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell: VideoCell = collectionView
        .dequeueReusableCell(indexPath: index) else { return UICollectionViewCell() }

    cell.data = anyData

    cell.onDoubleTapped = {
        print("DoubleTapped")
    }
}
```

Another alternate but improved approach would be to use one `UITapGestureRecognizer` from `ViewController` to detect the indexpath of the touched cell, get the relevant cell from that index, and execute actions and view updates based on that.